# replace values with NA in several columns

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset and wish to replace values in certain columns (VAR1, VAR2) with NA if they do not start with AA or DD.

Data:

```
DF<-tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,  ~VAR1,    ~VAR1DATE,  ~VAR2,    ~VAR2DATE,
   1L, "AABB", "2001-01-01", "BBAA", "2001-01-01",
   2L, "AACC", "2001-01-02", "AACC", "2001-01-02",
   3L, "CCDD", "2001-01-03", "DDCC", "2001-01-03",
   4L, "DDAA", "2001-01-04", "CCBB", "2001-01-04",
   5L, "CCBB", "2001-01-05", "CCBB", "2001-01-05"
  )
```

Desired output:

```
A tibble: 5 × 5
     ID VAR1  VAR1DATE   VAR2  VAR2DATE  
  <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
1     1 AABB  2001-01-01 NA    NA        
2     2 AACC  2001-01-02 AACC  2001-01-02
3     3 NA    NA         DDCC  2001-01-03
4     4 DDAA  2001-01-04 NA    NA        
5     5 NA    NA         NA    NA
```

Is there an elegant and smart way to this? `mutate_all`?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, fixed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may do this in two steps - loop `across` the columns that have 'VAR' followed by digits (`\\d+`) in column names, `replace` the values where the first two characters are not `AA` or `DD` to `NA`, then `replace` the corresponding `DATE` column to `NA` based on the `NA` in the 'VAR1', 'VAR2' columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DF %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^VAR\\d+$"),
        ~ replace(., !substr(., 1, 2)  %in% c("AA", "DD"), NA)), 
      across(ends_with("DATE"), 
     ~ replace(., is.na(get(str_remove(cur_column(), "DATE"))), NA)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
     ID VAR1  VAR1DATE   VAR2  VAR2DATE  
  <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
1     1 AABB  2001-01-01 <NA>  <NA>      
2     2 AACC  2001-01-02 AACC  2001-01-02
3     3 <NA>  <NA>       DDCC  2001-01-03
4     4 DDAA  2001-01-04 <NA>  <NA>      
5     5 <NA>  <NA>       <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Very nice soliution

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tidyverse solution. Using `across` with `str_replace_all` and appending two `ifelse` statements.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

DF %>% 
  mutate(across(c(VAR1, VAR2), ~str_replace_all(., "^[^AA|DD]", NA_character_))) %>% 
  mutate(VAR1DATE = ifelse(is.na(VAR1), NA_character_, VAR1DATE),
         VAR2DATE = ifelse(is.na(VAR2), NA_character_, VAR2DATE))
```

```
     ID VAR1  VAR1DATE   VAR2  VAR2DATE  
  <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
1     1 AABB  2001-01-01 NA    NA        
2     2 AACC  2001-01-02 AACC  2001-01-02
3     3 NA    NA         DDCC  2001-01-03
4     4 DDAA  2001-01-04 NA    NA        
5     5 NA    NA         NA    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `mutate/across` with the assignment function `is.na<-`.

```
DF %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("VAR"), \(x) `is.na<-`(x, !grepl("^AA|^DD", x))))
## A tibble: 5 x 5
#     ID VAR1  VAR1DATE VAR2  VAR2DATE
#  <int> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>   
#1     1 AABB  NA       NA    NA      
#2     2 AACC  NA       AACC  NA      
#3     3 NA    NA       DDCC  NA      
#4     4 DDAA  NA       NA    NA      
#5     5 NA    NA       NA    NA
```

Or simpler:

```
DF %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("VAR"), ~`is.na<-`(., !grepl("^AA|^DD", .))))
```

Comment: All dates are NA?

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, using `tidyr::unite` and `tiydr::separate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF<-tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,  ~VAR1,    ~VAR1DATE,  ~VAR2,    ~VAR2DATE,
  1L, "AABB", "2001-01-01", "BBAA", "2001-01-01",
  2L, "AACC", "2001-01-02", "AACC", "2001-01-02",
  3L, "CCDD", "2001-01-03", "DDCC", "2001-01-03",
  4L, "DDAA", "2001-01-04", "CCBB", "2001-01-04",
  5L, "CCBB", "2001-01-05", "CCBB", "2001-01-05"
)

DF %>% 
  unite(VAR1,VAR1,VAR1DATE) %>% unite(VAR2,VAR2,VAR2DATE) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("VAR"),~if_else(str_detect(.x, "^AA|^DD"), .x, NA_character_))) %>% 
  separate(VAR1,into = c("VAR1", "VAR1DATE"), sep = "_") %>% 
  separate(VAR2,into = c("VAR2", "VAR2DATE"), sep = "_")

#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>      ID VAR1  VAR1DATE   VAR2  VAR2DATE  
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
#> 1     1 AABB  2001-01-01 <NA>  <NA>      
#> 2     2 AACC  2001-01-02 AACC  2001-01-02
#> 3     3 <NA>  <NA>       DDCC  2001-01-03
#> 4     4 DDAA  2001-01-04 <NA>  <NA>      
#> 5     5 <NA>  <NA>       <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` solution with using `str_detect` to determine where to convert to `NA` for the date columns. Then, we can use the same type of function on `VAR1` and `VAR2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    VAR1DATE = ifelse(str_detect(VAR1, '^BB|^CC') == TRUE, NA, VAR1DATE),
    VAR2DATE = ifelse(str_detect(VAR2, '^BB|^CC') == TRUE, NA, VAR2DATE)
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(c(VAR1, VAR2), function(x)
    ifelse(str_detect(x, '^BB|^CC') == TRUE, NA, x)))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
# Rowwise: 
     ID VAR1  VAR1DATE   VAR2  VAR2DATE  
  <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
1     1 AABB  2001-01-01 NA    NA        
2     2 AACC  2001-01-02 AACC  2001-01-02
3     3 NA    NA         DDCC  2001-01-03
4     4 DDAA  2001-01-04 NA    NA        
5     5 NA    NA         NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a `Base R` solution could be simpler:

```
DF$VAR1DATE[grepl("(^[^AA|^DD].*$)", DF$VAR1)] <- NA
DF$VAR1[grepl("(^[^AA|^DD].*$)", DF$VAR1)] <- NA
DF$VAR2DATE[grepl("(^[^AA|^DD].*$)", DF$VAR2)] <- NA
DF$VAR2[grepl("(^[^AA|^DD].*$)", DF$VAR2)] <- NA
```

or with a loop:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(DF) 
for (i in 1:4) {
        DF[,2*(i%%2)+i][grepl("(^[^AA|^DD].*$)", DF[,i+(i%%2)])] <- NA
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
DF
# A tibble: 5 × 5
     ID VAR1  VAR1DATE   VAR2  VAR2DATE  
  <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
1     1 AABB  2001-01-01 NA    NA        
2     2 AACC  2001-01-02 AACC  2001-01-02
3     3 NA    NA         DDCC  2001-01-03
4     4 DDAA  2001-01-04 NA    NA        
5     5 NA    NA         NA    NA
```